# I can not put more menuItem() in shinydashboard

Tags: user-interface, shinydashboard

Here are my codes to build the user interface of my shiny dashboard:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)


## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Analyses de la concurrence inter-hospitalière en IDF"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarUserPanel(
      menuItem("Analyse des profils d'activité des hôpitaux",
               menuSubItem("Tableaux"),
               menuSubItem("Carte")),
      menuItem("Analyse de la concurrence",
               menuSubItem("Zone de recrutement"),
               menuSubItem("Part de marchés"),
               menuSubItem("Flux des patients"),
               menuSubItem("Indice de Herfindahl-Hirschmann")),
      menuItem("Analyse de trajectoires")
    )),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I tried to put three menu items in the sidebar panel and four menu sub-items in one of menu items. But when I put more than 2 menu items in the sidebar panel and more than 2 menu sub-items in a menu items the user interface is no longer properly displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `sidebarUserPanel()` to `sidebarMenu()`, and give a `width` of 300.  This works

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Analyses de la concurrence inter-hospitalière en IDF"),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 300,
    sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
      menuItem("Analyse des profils d'activité des hôpitaux",
               menuSubItem("Tableaux"),
               menuSubItem("Carte")),
      menuItem("Analyse de la concurrence",
               menuSubItem("Zone de recrutement"),
               menuSubItem("Part de marchés"),
               menuSubItem("Flux des patients"),
               menuSubItem("Indice de Herfindahl-Hirschmann")),
      menuItem("Analyse de trajectoires")
    )),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Just amazing. Thank you